# Multiboot liveCD with custom ISOs

Tags: ubuntu, livecd, truecrypt, dban

I want to create one bootable DVD, on which I would love to have

- Truecrypt rescueCD
- Ubuntu 10.10 liveCD
- DBAN

I have ISOs of all of above. Do you have any idea how to acomplish so?

Answer (score 1):

check this [multiCD](http://multicd.tuxfamily.org/#Downloads)